# Sending configuration data to websocket

Tags: php, websocket

I currently have the following scripts:

**Chat.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'core/Init.php';
$user = new User();    
$colours = array('007AFF','FF7000','FF7000','15E25F','CFC700','CFC700','CF1100','CF00BE','F00');
$user_colour = array_rand($colours);
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //create a new WebSocket object.
        var wsUri = "ws://199.188.203.97:9000/includes/server.php";
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

        websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open
            $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>"); //notify user
        }

        $('#chatform').submit(function(event){ //if user clicks message send button
            event.preventDefault();
            var mymessage = $('#message').val(); //get message text
            var myname = '<?php echo $user->data()->username; ?>'; //get user name

            if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
                alert("Enter Some message Please!");
                return;
            }

            //prepare json data
            var msg = {
                message: mymessage,
                name: myname,
                color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
            };
            //convert and send data to server
            websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        });

        //#### Message received from server?
        websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
            var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
            var type = msg.type; //message type
            var umsg = msg.message; //message text
            var uname = msg.name; //user name
            var ucolor = msg.color; //color

            if(type == 'usermsg')
            {
                $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></div>");
            }
            if(type == 'system')
            {
                $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</div>");
            }

            $('#message').val(''); //reset text
        };

        websocket.onerror   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</div>");};
        websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</div>");};
    });
</script>
<div id="chat" class="fixed" data-current-user="<?php echo $user->data()->username; ?>" data-order-by-status="1" data-max-chat-history="25">

    <!-- conversation template -->
    <div class="chat-outer">
        <div class="message_box" id="message_box" style="background-color: #fff;padding: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 10px;height: 90%;"></div>
        <form id="chatform">
            <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="80" autocomplete="off" style="width: 95%;margin-left: 10px;padding: 2px;" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Send">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="chatinner">
        <?php include("chatInner.php"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and 
**Server.php**

```
<?php


$host = 'localhost'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
            $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color

            //prepare data to be sent to client
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));
            send_message($response_text); //send data
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

Everything works fine but what I would like to do is have the username send to the server so if someone connects, it shows their username instead of the IP. Just wondering how I would go about doing this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using other peoples script, it's always good practice to reference where you found it :D ...

Ref: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

I've been playing around with this script aswell, it's really good :D

So, onto what I hope will answer your question ...

What you could do, is send the username in the `websocket.onopen` function (Formated so that the server can understand when a new username is being sent), and then alter the server.php code to then notify everyone of the new user ... So it would look something like this:

**Chat.php changes**

```
    websocket.onopen = function(ev) {
        $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>");
        //send username to server
        var msg = {
            newuser: '<?php echo $user->data()->username; ?>' 
        };
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
```

**Server.php changes**

```
if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
    $socket_new = socket_accept($socket);
    $clients[] = $socket_new;

    $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024);
    perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port);

    //remove the code that sends the IP
    //socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip);
    //$response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected')));
    //send_message($response);

    $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
    unset($changed[$found_socket]);
}
```

..

```
foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

    while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
    {
        $received_text = unmask($buf);
        $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text);
        //check if the 'newuser' has been recieved, otherwise send a normal message
        if(isset($tst_msg->newuser)) {
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$tst_msg.' joined the room')));
            send_message($response);
        } else {
            $user_name = $tst_msg->name;
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message;
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color;

            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));
            send_message($response_text);
        }

        break 2;
    }
```

Hope this helps :D